# Adding two values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
A      B        C         Value
1990    1   1   0.791684449
1990    1   2   0.058315583
1990    2   3   2.940000057
1990    3   4   8.975000381
1990    4   5   0
1990    4   6   0.004666695
1990    4   7   0.401333332
1990    5   8   2.609000206
1990    6   9   6.400992393
1990    6   10  9.489910126
1990    6   11  1.31809783
1990    7   12  214.4270172
1990    8   13  0.097975887
1990    8   14  0.680250943
1990    8   15  9.270773888
1990    9   16  1.204782724
1990    9   17  4.113919258
1990    9   18  3.486953974
1990    9   19  1.675345063
1990    10  20  0.434966862
1990    10  21  2.561163187
1990    10  22  2.415041685
1990    10  23  2.660344124
1990    10  24  7.127485275
```

Now I want to add only those values whose B is same & display in a table according to the C like:

```
1990        1   0.850000031
1990        2   2.940000057
1990        3   8.975000381
1990        4   0.406000027
1990        5   2.609000206
1990        6   17.20900035
```

How can I do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `SUM`.

Try this SQL:

```
SELECT A, B, SUM(Value) AS TotalValue
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY A, B
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fa89/1)

See the documentation for more details:

- [GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks Mark! I got my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use [*AGGREGATE FUNCTION*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) `SUM()` to calculate the total values and grouped them by `A` and `B`

```
SELECT A, B, SUM(c) totalValue
FROM tableName
GROUP BY A, B
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e859/2)

Comment: you're welcome @Rashid. please take time to read the link above :D

Answer (score 0):

select A,B, sum(value)
from table
group by B,A

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A, min(c) c,SUM(value) totalValue
FROM tableName
GROUP BY A, B
```